# Changing Verbose colors in PowerShell 7.2

Tags: powershell, colors, powershell-core, verbose

I expected the following code to print verbose text with my default foreground color:

```
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = [console]::ForegroundColor
Write-Verbose 'Test' -Verbose
```

However, it prints yellow text as usual. Changing the Error foreground color *does* work though:

```
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = [console]::ForegroundColor
Write-Error 'test'
```

The only way I've found to circumvent this is by doing this:

```
Write-Verbose 'Test' -Verbose *>&1 | Write-Host
```

But this isn't really changing the verbose colors, it's just forcing it to print directly to the console host as default text using Write-Host. I do know that Write-Host does let you alter the message color to anything you want, but this is hardly an ideal solution.

Comment: `$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = [console]::ForegroundColor.ToString()`?

Comment: Hmm `(get-host).privatedata.verboseforegroundcolor = 'Gray'` works in ps 5 but not ps 7.  Using `$psstyle.Foreground.White` doesn't work.  My test is `echo hi > there; rm there -v`

Comment: @JosefZ That doesn't make a difference, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Powershell 7.2+`, `$Host.PrivateData` not the right way to set styles. It's there for backwards compatibility. For details, see a brand new `about_*` page: [about_ANSI_Terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.2)

You want

[image]

```
$PSStyle.Formatting.Verbose = $PSStyle.Foreground.FromRgb(0x34f2aa)
```

Check out the docs, it adds a bunch of options: bold, blink, hidden, reverse, italic, underline, fileinfo.... [about_ANSI_Terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.2#psstyle)

### Test it out

```
function testVerbose { 
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param( [Parameter() ]$x )
   "$x"
   $X.GetType().FullName | write-verbose
   
}

testVerbose 34.5 -Verbose                                             ; 

$PSStyle.Formatting.Verbose = $PSStyle.Foreground.FromRgb(0x34f2aa)

testVerbose 34.5 -Verbose
```

### Viewing ansi escapes

One way to view the `ANSI` control chars is to replace "``e".

```
# I saved the value before changing it
$originalVerbose -replace "`e", ''

$PSStyle.Formatting.Verbose -replace "`e", ''
```

[image]

Notice: It switched to the [**24bit-color** ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#24-bit)

### Printing all control chars

[Format-ControlChar](https://github.com/ninmonkey/Ninmonkey.Console/blob/0ab14195163593dfe7f9249162ea61cd243cb9f4/public/Format-ControlChar.ps1) converts all control chars to their `Symbol` version, not just `e`, making values  safe to pipe.

It's easy, just add 0x2400 to the codepoint. [compart.com/block/U+2400](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2400)

```
> "$($PSStyle.Background.BrightCyan)Power$($PSStyle.Underline)$($PSStyle.Bold)Shell$($PSStyle.Reset)"
    | Format-ControlChar

␛[106mPower␛[4m␛[1mShell␛[0m
```